# splitting up a file: substitute `egrep` in `sed`

Tags: linux, bash, sed, bash-scripting, egrep

I want to split my *$file* containing *x* lines in half, and check how many lines contain "*dead*" in a log.  I started off with the following:

```
half=`expr $(egrep -c . $file) / 2`

sed -n 1,${half}p $file | 
    xargs echo $file $half $(egrep -c dead $I) > log_1
sed -n ${half},${egrep -c . $file}p | 
    xargs echo $file $half $(egrep -c dead $I) > log_2
```

output for the first `sed` command is ok, but when substituting `egrep` in the range of `sed` it goes wrong:

```
DeadOrAlive 5 2
-bash: ${half},${egrep -c . $file}p: bad substitution
```

Is there a more efficient way of splitting the file in `bash`?

Comment: `$(...)` and `${...}` are different constructs. The former is command substitution, the latter is parameter expansion.

Comment: Your first `egrep` counts non-empty lines.  `grep -c ^ file` would produce the total line count, including empty lines. (If your file doesn't contain any empty lines, then of course both are equivalent.) `wc -l <file` is probably faster because it doesn't need to do any regex matching. If you want to specifically count non-empty lines, then of course you do have to check for matches.

Comment: What do you expect `$I` to contain?

Comment: `sed "$half,\$"` will select lines from `$half` through to the end of file, though your code will include the middlemost file (line number `$half`) in both the first and the second half.

Comment: `sed "1,${half}d" file` will delete the first `$half` lines, and print the rest. With that, you can get the file properly split into two non-overlapping partitions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `wc`, `head` and `tail`:

   ```
   half=$(( $(wc -l "$file")/2 ))
   head -$half | egrep -c dead | xargs echo "$file" $half > log_1
   tail -$half | egrep -c dead | xargs echo "$file" $half > log_2
   ```
2. Using `split`:

   ```
   split -a1 --numeric-suffixes=1 -n 'l/2' "$file" "$file"_
   echo "$file" "$file"_1 $(egrep -c dead "$file_1") > log_1
   echo "$file" "$file"_2 $(egrep -c dead "$file"_2) > log_2
   rm "$file"_[12]
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Awk solution.

```
awk '/dead/ { a[++n] = NR }
    END { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) if (a[i] > NR/2) break
        print ARGV, int(NR/2), i-1 >"log_1";
        print ARGV, int(NR/2)+(int(NR/2)!=NR/2), n-i+1 >"log_2" }' file
```

We collect into the array `a` the line numbers of the matches. We then figure out how many of the line numbers in the array are smaller than the middlemost line; their count is assigned to the first partition. (We have to use `i-1` because we are already past the partitioning point when we `break` out of the loop.)

In general, you want to avoid rereading the same file many times, especially if it might be big; and secondly, try to minimize the number of processes.

It's not clear what you expect the middle output field to contain. If the file contains an odd number of lines, the first "half" will contain one line less than the second partition. (This is not hard to change, but you have to decide one way or the other.)

Comment: Strictly speaking, we should `close()` the files we open, but as long as there are only two, I didn't bother.